# Question on the moment of inertia of solid sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I've read the questions on the topic, but couldn't find one that addresses my concern. When I attempted calculating the moment of inertia by partitioning the sphere into solid discs, each disc has radius $r$ and thickness $dz$. The volume element is $dV=4\pi r^2\, dz$. Now, $r$ is related to the angle $\theta$ a radius makes with the $z$ axis by $r=R \sin\theta$. And $z$ is a function of $\theta$ given by $z=R\cos\theta$. So, $dz= -R \sin\theta\, d\theta$. The integral is now $$I = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{2}r^2\,dm = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{2}r^2 \frac{M}{V} 4\pi r^2 \,dz = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{2} R^2 (\sin^2\theta) \frac {M}{V} 4\pi (R^2\sin^2 \theta) (-R\sin\theta) \,d\theta.$$
Now, when I integrate over $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$, I get a negative sign and a moment of inertia of $\frac{-2}{5}MR^2$. I can't find the mistake, so can someone point it out?

Comment: Your limits on the $dm$ and $dz$ integrals don’t make sense.

Comment: @Ghoster right, I substituted the limits on the final integral in all integrals. It's wrong, but it's certainly not the problem with the question.